# Как сделать, что бы по нажатию Tab игнорировался фокус на RadioGroup?

Tags: delphi, vcl

Есть RadioGroup. Пытался сделать `TabStop := false`, но именно на этом элементе не помогает, а на остальных работает, то есть по нажатию на кнопку tab все равно фокусируется на RadioGroup1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Свойство `RadioGroup.TabStop` относится к самой радиогруппе, но не к кнопкам, что расположены на ней. А вот у кнопок поведение интересное: каждая кнопка имеет своё свойство `TabStop`, которое изменяется **автоматически**. Логика изменения такая - если кнопка отмечена (стоит точка), то у этой кнопки свойство `TabStop` устанавливается в `True`, а всем остальным кнопкам в этой группе, оно сбрасывается в `False`.

Чтобы изменить это автоматическое поведение, нужно в рантайме, в событии `OnClick` у радиогруппы, вручную сбросить свойство `TabStop` для всех кнопок:

```
procedure TForm1.rg1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to rg1.Items.Count - 1 do begin
    rg1.Buttons[I].TabStop := False;
  end;
end;
```

Если при создании формы у вас есть какая-то кнопка отмеченная по умолчанию, такой сброс нужно делать и в `OnShow` этой формы. Поэтому, чтобы код не дублировался, лучше его вынести в отдельный метод, вроде `ResetTabStop` и дёргать его из `RadioGroup.OnClick` и `Form.OnShow`.